# ElasticSearch, how to search for a document containing a specific array element

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a little problem with elasticsearch and wonder if someone can help me solve it.

I have a document containing an array of tuples (publications).

Something like :

```
    {
       ....

       publications: [
         {
           item1: 385294,
           item2: 11
         },
         {
           item1: 395078,
           item2: 1
         }
       ]

       ....
    }
```

The problem i have is for retrieving documents who contain a specific tuple, for exemple (item1 = 395078 AND item2 = 1).

Whatever i try, it seems to always treat item1 and item2 separately, i fail to tell elasticsearch that item1 and item2 must have a specific value inside the same tuple, not accross the whole array...

Is there something i'm missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the straight way.
ElasticSearch flattens the array before checking for condition.
Which mean 
elasticSearch matches 
a=x AND b=y1 to  [{a=x,b=y},{a=x1,b=y1}] which doesnt happen in the conventianal array checking.

What you can do here is

- Usage of nested type - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html (but for each element in array , an extra document would be created)
- Store the array as
  publications: [
       {
         385294:11
       },
       {
         395078:1
       }
     ]

Comment: Thank you, i will look at nested types tomorrow. One more question, if store publications like this : publications: [ { 385294:11 }, { 395078:1 } ] how can it help me with my query ?

Comment: If you have the value of item1 beforehead , you can query for the value of 385294 in the array. And it will give as 11.